# rxjs from array execute one by one in same order

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I need to execute observables created from array. The condition is next observable should wait until previous observable has been completed. Thanks in advance :-).

```
export class AppComponent{
    arr: number[] = [5, 4, 1, 2, 3];    
    fetchWithObs() {
        from(this.arr)
          .pipe(
            map((value) => {
              return this.getData(value);
            })
          )
          .subscribe((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            /**
             * The expoected output should be
             * 5 completed
             * 4 completed
             * 1 completed
             * 2 completed
             * 3 completed
             */
          });
      }
    
      getData(p: number) {
        return new Observable<string>((s) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            s.next(`${p} completed`);
            s.complete();
          }, p * 1000);
        });
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `concatMap`.

```
export class AppComponent{
    arr: number[] = [5, 4, 1, 2, 3];    
    fetchWithObs() {
        from(this.arr)
          .pipe(
            concatMap(this.getData)
          )
          .subscribe(console.log);
      }
    
      getData(p: number) {
        return new Observable<string>((s) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            s.next(`${p} completed`);
            s.complete();
          }, p * 1000);
        });
      }
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-axx8gf?file=index.ts